# XAML Go to visualState defined by binding

Tags: silverlight, xaml, expression-blend

I don't have very much experience with XAML or expression blend yet.  I am trying to make the initial visualState of my silverlight application be defined by a string binding.

So far, I am simply making a manual trigger for each possible visualstate:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding VisualState}" Value="DevOffline">
        <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="DevOffline"/>
    </ei:DataTrigger>
    <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding VisualState}" Value="Public">
        <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="Public"/>
    </ei:DataTrigger>
    ....
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

It works, but I have 9 states in total, so I would like something universal like:

```
<goToStateAction StateName="{Binding VisualState}" />
```

Is it possible to do this?  If so, where do I put it in my XAML?  The same place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The StateName property on the GoToStateAction behavior is a dependency property, so it seems like you should be able to bind to it.  Just replace the DataTrigger with a PropertyChangedTrigger.  It seems like you should be able to do the following:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ei:PropertyChangedTrigger Binding="{Binding VisualState}">
        <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="{Binding VisualState}"/>
    </ei:PropertyChangedTrigger >
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```